# convert date/time

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Right now in my code, I have

> $('#StartDateTime').val(new
>   Date(event.start).toLocaleDateString()
>   + " " + (event.start).toLocaleTimeString());

which this displays "Thursday, July 22, 2010 8:00:00 AM". I was wondering if anyone could help me on how I could convert it to just plain "07/22/2010 08:00 am"?

I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to end up doing something like this.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7exrR/

```
var date = new Date(event.start);

var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var d = date.getDate();
var y = date.getFullYear(); 
var t = date.toLocaleTimeString().toLowerCase().replace(/:\d\d ([ap]m) .+$/,' $1');

$('#StartDateTime').val( m + '/' + d + '/' + y + ' ' + t );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```